# How can I add a restriction rule to the discount when a sale is going to be made in odoo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, odoo

I have a custom section called layout_category_id, which lists a series of items. The mentioned items are 4 in total and each one has its respective id.
What I am trying to do is that when the id of layout_category_id is different from 1, no discount can be applied.

I made a code in js that makes that comparison that works only at a visual level ... well, even if the discount is assigned or equal, it continues to apply the discount if it was previously added.

`

```
_computeAggregates: function () {
        var self = this;
        var data = [];
        var datos = 0;
        try {
            datos = this.state.data.length;
            if (datos >= 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < datos; i++) {
                    if (this.state.data[i]['data'].layout_category_id.data) {
                        // preguntamos si es distinto a alquileres
                        if (this.state.data[i]['data'].layout_category_id.data.id != 1) {
                            this.state.data[i]['data']['discount'] = 0.00;
                        }
                        // console.log(this.state.data[i]['data']);
                    } 
                }
            }
        } catch(err) {
          console.log(err.message);
        }
        if (this.selection.length) {
            console.log('entro mal');
            utils.traverse_records(this.state, function (record) {
                if (_.contains(self.selection, record.id)) {
                    data.push(record); // find selected records
                }
            });
        } else {
            // xnet
            data = this.state.data;
        }
        _.each(this.columns, this._computeColumnAggregates.bind(this, data));
    },
```

`

Initially I wanted to do it in XML in this way but obviously it did not work
`<field t-if="layout_category_id == 1" name="discount" class="descuento" groups="sale.group_discount_per_so_line"/>`
[image: my array]